# How to check currentPassword to allow user to change Password

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, mern

im trying to implement function for "user change password".

- i want to do:

1.user choose new password.

2.user needs to enter his current password to varificate.

3.if the user currentPassword correct -> change the password.

**the problem**: i dont know how to get his current password to check if its correct

- in my client side i save his hashPassword ("lfds7fdhas784n23489h42")

  so i **cant** do something like:

  if state.user.password===currentPassword because i dont have its state password
- i need to somhow get his passwsord from the server and check it, or maybe i need to send the
  currentPassword to the back end and check it there ,but i dont know how to implement it...

**code**:

1. the Form to update password (in shortcut for better understanding):

   ```
     <TextInput
     placeholder"NewPassword"
     onChangeText={setNewPass}/>

     <TextInput
     placeholder"currentPassword"
     onChangeText={setCurrentPass}/>

     updateUserPssword(state.userId, token, param, value);
   ```
2. the Function for update the password:
   const updateUserPssword = dispatch => async (userId, token, newPass, currentPass) => {

   ```
    try {
    const res = await indexApi.put(
        `/user/${userId}`,
        {
            password: newPass,
        },
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        }
    );
    }
   ```

Comment: Basically, you should send the raw password to server, in server, they know which hash algorithm use before storing password to db. So the server will handle that for you.

Comment: can u give me example how to do it?

Comment: What you need to do is passing `oldPassword` and the pair of `newPassword` to server. All things relates to password should be handled by server, if the current password is incorrect, server returns an error for you. You should not store the hash password in state as well, why you need to do that ?

Comment: The only thing you can handle on client is the similarity of new passwords pair.

Comment: ok so first: i dont going to save the password, u right,
second: you can show me how to pass the currentPassword to the implemention code of the axios? where to put it ? inside headers? inside param:{} ? how i send it

Answer (score 1):

**For summary, the flow of reset password operation is like:**

- Step 1: User fills in `currentPassword`, `newPassword` and `confirmedNewPassword` in your React App. What you can validate here is only the similatiry of `newPassword` and `confirmNewPassword`.
- Step 2: When the `newPassword` and `comfirmedNewPassword` are similar you send a request to server with data like this : `{ current: currentPassword, new: newPassword }`

Your main concern is how to do that with `axios`. Below is an example:

```
axios.post('/reset-password', {
    current: currentPassword,
    new: newPassword
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    // success case handle here
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // error case handle here
  });
```

When your server gets this request, basically, the following steps should be done

- Step 1: Use hash function to hash the `currentPassword`
- Step 2: Compare with hashed password of this user in DB
- Step 2.1: If the 2 hashed passwords match, hash the `newPassword` and save the hashed value to DB
- Step 2.2: If the 2 hashed passwords do not match, response error to your React App. (something like: `passwords do not match`)

Answer (score 0):

You should manipulate all your actions on passwords on the server-side. That's the right flow

1. User types new password (Don't hash)
2. User types same password for confirmation (you can compare only this on client-side, if fieldA.value == fieldB.value)
3. User types old password
4. You send new password and old password as plain, to the server without hash.
5. Server hashes your old password with the same SALT and compares if generated hash is equal to the hash is stored in the database. That's the KEY MOMENT, you don't need to decode a stored password and compare the plain.

P.S Every time hashing something with the same salt gives you the
same result.

```
// Pseudo code
decodeHash(passwordInDatabase) == oldPassword // incorrect + impossible
hash(oldPassword) == passwordInDatabase // correct
```

6. If it's equal, back-end hash your new password and update in the database.
7. Return success or error message from back-end.